# Dynamic way to use string/array as index of object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got a structure of files and folders in a directory structured like the "example_object" I describe below. I also have paths of each of the files as strings.

So my solution is to split the path into an array, and then use the array to index the object as described in the function below. The length of the array will vary as I don't know how many levels of folders there will be.

Whilst what I've written below works, and I guess is only 4 lines, I see a lot of users get anxious about using "eval". It also seems an indirect method to get the job done. Any improvements/alternate ways to do this?

```js
function change_object_using_path_string(this_object,this_path,new_value){
  var array_as_index = this_path.split("/");    
  array_as_index = "['"+array_as_index.join("']['")+"']";
  var code_to_eval = this_object+array_as_index+"='"+new_value+"'";
  eval(code_to_eval);  
}
```

The above function is what I'm actually using in my script. The below code reflects the structure of the inputs I would put into the above function:

// NOTE: I'm only inputting "example_object" into 'change_object_using_path_string' as a string to facilitate the eval solution I'm using. I would prefer a solution which directly inputs example_object into the function.

```js
example_object = {
  folder_1_name:{
    folder_2_name:{
      folder_3_name:{
        'file.txt':'this file content'  
      }
    }
  }
}
example_path = "folder_1_name/folder_2_name/folder_3_name/file.txt";

change_object_using_path_string("example_object",example_path,"new content instead");
```

Comment: There's at least 2 problems with this question: 1) it isn't working as intended. On Code Review, code not working as intended is not fit for review and 2) it's example code. This is not your actual code. Examples are off-topic at Code Review, since the chance of writing an answer you gain nothing from is too high and the context required for a good answer is missing. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Mast Sorry - I can't currently ask questions on StackOverflow (where I think the format would have been acceptable?), and formatted it for it. Just out of curiosity, would this question have been acceptable on Stack Overflow as is? I've tried to improve my old questions on it to regain the right to ask questions, but I can't see anything more I can do.

Comment: This is not Stack Overflow. Posting it here because you couldn't post it where you should've posted it is something you really shouldn't even consider. Do that at your work once too often and nobody will want to help you. It may have worked over there, but a little clarification wouldn't have hurt. The length of the index variable can vary. Yea, so? How often? When exactly? What are you using this solution for that your index varies halfway the look-up? There may be a better solution out there, depending on what exactly you're trying to do and why.

Comment: Ok, point taken. I'll be more careful to check the guidelines before posting on any of the stackexchange websites. Apologies for misusing codereview. Thanks for the suggestions about how to better format the question for SO.

Comment: @Mast Apologies again for my first attempt at posting this on Code Review. I've tried to change the question to one that is acceptable for Code Review. Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: @Mast or anyone else reading - is there anything more that I need to do to this question to get it reopened? I waited 5 days for my edits to be reviewed, and after reading [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) it looks like the next step would be to ask on the meta website - is that right?

Comment: This question is being discussed on [Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8584).

Comment: I think it would make it a lot clearer that this is a production function by separating the example input from the function definition, putting the former towards the end of the post.

Comment: @Graipher Thanks, that makes sense, I've put the example input at the end clarifying it's not part of the code that I use, whilst the function is code I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fairly straightforward to do this without using `eval`. For example, a statement like `obj['a']['b']['c']['d'] = 'value';` can be rewritten as a series of smaller steps:

```
var temp = obj;
temp = temp['a'];      // member access
temp = temp['b'];      // member access
temp = temp['c'];      // member access
temp['d'] = 'value';   // assignment
```

Now, it shouldn't be too hard to see how those member access statements can be rolled into a loop, if you have an array of indexes (which you do).

---

A few other notes:

- It's good to see descriptive names, but `change_object_using_path_string` strikes me as a bit too long and unwieldy. What about something like `set_path_value`?
- You may want to use some more spacing between function parameters (`param1,param2` vs `param1, param2`) and operators (`a+b` vs `a + b`). This makes individual parts stand out more, making the code a little easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the comments about clarity also :-)